# Best way to change the default bundle id and Rename the React Native app (Android and iOS)

Tags: android, react-native

How to change the default Bundle ID and the App name of my React-Native app?

Previously I use the "[react-native-rename](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-rename)" package but Now it's deprecated, for reference please check the below image.

[image].

Please help me to resolve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

If your project is small - try init the clean project and copy&paste your code

Comment: Want to change the default Bundle ID(com.abc to com.companyname.abc) of my application

Comment: you can just change the value from android/app/build.gradle and Xcode, but many other files can have old package name (for example several android files have package name in files name)